# How to change background color when touching a div using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a mouse labyrinth maze using Html, Css and Javascript. where you will lose if you touch any of the walls with your mouse cursor. However, i want to make the background color of the maze red when you touch one of the walls in the maze (game over).

```
    var boundaries = document.querySelectorAll(".boundary");
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var end = document.querySelector("#end");
var status = document.querySelector("#status");
var win = true;

  start.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Move the mouse cursor over to "E" to win";
    for (var i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
      boundaries[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        win = false;
        this.style.background = "red";
        alert("You lost, try again!");
        this.style.background = "#eeeeee";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "You lost!";
      });
    }

  });

end.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if (win == true) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "You won!";
    alert("Gongratulations! You won!");
  }
  win = true;
});
```

in html i am using class to make the walls

```
  <div id="maze">
        <div id="start">S</div>
        <div class="boundary" id="boundary1"></div>
        <div class="boundary"></div>
        <div class="boundary"></div>
        <div class="boundary"></div>
        <div class="boundary"></div>
```

Comment: I can see two defects 1) `"Move the mouse cursor over to "E" to win";` Either you have to remove the quotes around `E` or put it inside single quote

2. There is no element with  `id` '`end`

Comment: There's also no element `id="status"` but I guess we miss some of the HTML. Apart from these it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the walls of the maze are given by th divs with class `boundary`, I think you just need to add an event listener too all those divs. Something like in this fiddle:

```js
var boundaries = document.querySelectorAll(".boundary");
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var end = document.querySelector("#end");
var status = document.querySelector("#status");
var win = true;

  start.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Move the mouse cursor over to 'E' to win";
    for (var i = 0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
      boundaries[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        win = false;
        this.style.background = "red";
        alert("You lost, try again!");
        this.style.background = "#eeeeee";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "You lost!";
      });
    }

  });


const walls = document.querySelectorAll(".boundary");

walls.forEach(wallDOM => {
   wallDOM.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        document.getElementById("maze").style.background = "red";
    });
});

document.getElementById("resetButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("maze").style.background = "black";
    });
```

```css
#maze {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

#boundary1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#boundary2 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 250px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

#boundary3 {
  width: 125px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 45px;
}

#boundary4 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  right: 0;
}

#boundary5 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="maze">
   <div id="start">S</div>
   <div class="boundary" id="boundary1"></div>
   <div class="boundary" id="boundary2"></div>
   <div class="boundary" id="boundary3"></div>
   <div class="boundary" id="boundary4"></div>
   <div class="boundary" id="boundary5"></div>
</div>

<button id="resetButton">Reset BG</button>
```

Comment: Actually, look again at the question, your code adds something that is already done in original code. It's just that the OP sets the "walls" listeners only when you hover `start`. See: `boundaries[i].addEventListener`

Comment: You are right indeed, my bad. I honestly lost track of that part of his code